# SlidingDrawer everywhere

Tags: android, android-activity, slidingdrawer

I've an app with multiple activities and I'm using a SlidingDrawer in each one to pass from one activity to another. I started this app when I had no idea of Android, so in every activity I'm declaring all the elements inside the SlidingDrawer, e.g: I've `Act1.java` and `Act2.java` and inside the SlidingDrawer I've two buttons: one that targets to the `Act1.java` and the other targets to the `Act2.java` but when I'm in `Act1.java`, the button that targets to this activity is `INVISIBLE`.

Ok, my question is: Can I create a `slider.xml` with all the elements and a `Slider.java` to control the elements behavior so that every time I start a new activity, the content of the `Slider.java` is 'loaded' and the SlidingDrawer is shown correctly?

Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT: Like in PHP when we call `requiered_once(slider.php);` but for Java-Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using `Fragments` (read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)). They are designed to let you reuse certain UI elements in multiple activities. They were introduced in Honeycomb, but they are included in the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html), making it possible to use them all the way back to API level 4 (Donut).

If you just want to reuse the layout, you could just use the `<include>` xml tag in your layout. Here's a really good blog post by Romain Guy about including layouts: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/

Comment: Thank you VERY much for the information and fonts! I'll try it and when I get what I want I'll check your answer as the correct one :)